Query in 2sxc seems not to work after upgrading to 18.0.0
I recently upgraded 2sxc to 18.0.0 on an installation.
And in some apps we are using a database query (sql data block in the query designer).
For some reason when I test it, it says:
{
  "Default": [
    {
      "SourceStream": "Default",
      "Error": "Error: Can't read from Database",
      "Message": "Something failed trying to read from the Database.",
      "SourceName": "Sql",
      "DebugNotes": "There should be more details in the insights logs, see https://go.2sxc.org/insights",
      "SourceType": "Sql",
      "SourceLabel": "Sql",
      "SourceGuid": [],
      "Id": 0,
      "Guid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "Title": "Error: Can't read from Database",
      "Modified": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "Created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
    }
  ]
}

However, when I try to execute the query directly on the db it works fine...
So it looks like it can't see the connection string or something like that.
I've tried changing the connection to Default database (DNN/Oqtane) and SiteSqlServer (DNN) but that did not work...
Any idea what it could be?

Which SQL DataSource are you using Sql or Dnn? Can you show your settings in Visual Query? Also, I recommend upgrading to v18.02.00 to ensure the problem was not a bug that was already/recently fixed. Thanks!

Whenever you see something like this, it's best to have a look at the Insights. It will probably show you the problem.
Most of the internal errors are not surfaced to the user, as the error could contain confidential information.

We had a similar problem and thought the issues was in the Value Filter. Finally compared what we were doing with a v16.09.x site we had handy for testing - everything worked there. Realized we were on 2sxc v18.01.00... upgraded to v18.02.00 and everything worked immediately. Not sure what was fixed, but I am glad it did.

awesome, glad to hear it was resolved.

...best mark as answered, so it's not listed as an open question.

I wish I could, but upgrading to 2sxc 18.2 did not solve it.
It looks like sql queries without parameters seem to work, so, just simple Select statements are ok, but as soon as I user parameters, this is the error I get...

You should really check what the insights say. Maybe you've added the parameters incorrectly or something.

We've seen similar errors in Visual Query on both 2sxc v18.00 and v18.01. In all cases the fix was to upgrade to v18.02.00 or higher. I hope that works for you!
